# How to formally prove using first-order set theory that $\{7,8,9\}=\{7,8,10\}$ is a false statement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Consider $\{7,8,9\}$ and $\{7,8,10\}$ to be the informal representations of two sets. Formally, in naive first-order set theory, we define these sets as

$$\exists a\  \forall x\ (x \in a \iff (x=7 \lor x=8 \lor x=9))$$
$$\exists b\  \forall x\ (x \in b \iff (x=7 \lor x=8 \lor x=10))$$

**How do we formally prove, using naive first-order set theory, that these sets are different?**

Note that informally, I believe we could prove it thus:

> From the Axiom of Comprehension and Axiom of Extensionality, we can
> prove that for each well-formed formula P(x) in FOL, there is a unique
> set of objects that satisfy P(x).
>
> Let's assume this proof has already been given. Then since the objects
> satisfying $P_1(x)=x=7 \lor x=8 \lor x=9$ are different from the objects
> satisfying $P_2(x)=x=7 \lor x=8 \lor x=10$, the unique sets made of
> objects satisfying each of these formulas are different.

**Here is the line of reasoning of my incomplete attempt at a formal proof, using first-order logic:**

I take the two definitions of the sets as premises. I start with a subproof by existential elimination, with the premise:

- Assume a is a set such that $\forall x\ (x \in a \iff (x=7 \lor x=8 \lor x=9))$.

Nested within, I start another subproof by existential elimination, with the premise:

- Assume b is a set such that $\forall x\ (x \in v \iff (x=7 \lor x=8 \lor x=10))$.

The Axiom of Extensionality says

$$\forall a\ \forall b\ [\forall x\ (x \in a \iff x \in b) \implies a=b]$$

By Universal Elimination, I can state

$$\forall x\ (x \in a \iff x \in b) \implies a=b\tag{1}$$

At this point, I have a material conditional, and I want to prove $a \neq b$.

If I assume $a=b$, $(1)$ doesn't actually let me do anything with this assumption. In fact, using just the two Axioms (Comprehension and Extensionality) $a=b$ doesn't seem to lead to any other statement that I can infer.

After all, it seems to be the case that $\forall x\ (x \in a \iff x \in b)$ can be false and $a=b$ true, since we don't have a biconditional (another source of doubt for me in this material).

**Edit: What do I mean by FOL?**

I learned what I imagine is a very basic form of FOL which includes introduction and elimination inference rules for $\land,\lor,\implies,\iff,\lnot$, quantifiers $\forall, \exists$, introduction and elimination inference rules for $\forall$ and $\exists$, plus the identity predicate.

When naive set theory was introduced to me, there was only one symbol, $\in$, the Axiom of Comprehension, and the Axiom of Extensionality.

Axiom of Comprehension

$$\exists a \forall [x \in a \iff P(x)]$$

Axiom of Extensionality

$$\forall a \forall b [\forall x (x \in a \iff x \in b) \implies a = b]$$

Comment: Formally speaking, in the most annoying sense of the word, the symbols $7,8,9,10$ are not part of the language of set theory. So unless you provide explicit definitions of them, we cannot determine if the two sets are equal or not.

Comment: Use [Substitution axiom for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms): $A=B → (x∈A ↔ x∈B)$. Assuming $A=B$ we deduce that $∀x(x ∈ \{ 7,8,9 \} ↔ x ∈ \{ 7,8,10 \})$. From it, by [Universal Instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation), we derive: $9 ∈ \{ 7,8,9 \} ↔ 9 ∈ \{ 7,8,10 \}$ which is False. Having deduced a contradiction, we apply [Negation Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_introduction) to conclude with: $\lnot (A = B)$.

Comment: The needed instance of the equality axiom is: $A=B \to ((x \in z)[A/z] \leftrightarrow (x \in z)[B/z])$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extensionality to prove that $\{ 7, 8, 9 \} \neq \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$.$^*$ Simply observe that $9 \in \{7, 8, 9 \}$ but $9 \notin \{7, 8, 10 \}$, therefore $\{ 7, 8, 9 \} \neq \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$.

If you want to write this last step in more detail, you could say that if $9 \in \{ 7, 8, 9 \}$ and $\{ 7, 8, 9 \} = \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$, then $9 \in \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$, but this is false, hence $\{ 7, 8, 9 \} \neq \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$.

Edit: since you ask for a formal proof:

1. $\forall x (x \in \{ 7, 8, 9 \} \leftrightarrow (x = 7 \vee x = 8 \vee x = 9))$.
2. $\forall x (x \in \{ 7, 8, 10 \} \leftrightarrow (x = 7 \vee x = 8 \vee x = 10))$.
3. $9 \in \{ 7, 8, 9 \}$. (By universal instantiation. Take $x = 9$ in 1.)
4. $9 \notin \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$. (By universal instantiation. Take $x = 9$ in 2.)
5. $\{ 7, 8, 9 \} = \{ 7, 8, 10 \} \rightarrow (9 \in \{ 7, 8, 9 \} \rightarrow 9 \in \{ 7, 8, 10 \})$. (This, or some equivalent formula, is an instance of an axiom of predicate logic with equality.)
6. $\{ 7, 8, 9 \} \neq \{ 7, 8, 10 \}$. (By propositional logic.)

$^*$ Although if extensionality did not hold, then one could not make much sense of the notation $\{ 7, 8, 9 \}$ in the first place, since $\{ 7, 8, 9 \}$ is defined to be the unique set (unique by extensionality!) which contains the elements $7, 8, 9$ and nothing else.

Comment: I'd like a very formal proof utilizing exactly the rules of inference available to FOL. No English explanations, only statements in FOL and the inference rules used to make those statements. Obviously, the thing I am trying to prove is obvious with English available.

Comment: @evianpring Better now?

Comment: @evianpring "The rules of inference available to FOL" depend on which exact system you are using, whereas the informal English argument is more robust and independent of the precise formal system. You will notice that the "formal proof" I gave you really skips some steps whose precise implementation would depend on how you choose to formalize FOL.

Comment: I think you actually used the axiom of extensionality? How did you justify the two sets are different by finding an element of a set that is not in the other set?

Comment: @Hermis14 The axiom of extensionality states that if two sets have the same elements, then they are equal. That two sets *cannot* be equal if one contains an element that the other one does not is simply a basic principle of first-order logic, namely that identical objects have the same properties. (This is the same principle at play which allows us to infer e.g. that $m \neq n$ if $m$ is even but $n$ is not even.) That $\exists x (x \in y \wedge x \notin z) \rightarrow (y \neq z)$ is true is simply a matter of first-order logic, independent of any axioms of set theory.

Comment: I mean, you are dealing with sets in ZF, and the axioms say how two objects (sets) can be said to be identical. So you must use the axioms to say that the objects are different.

Comment: @Hermis14 No, the principle $x = y \rightarrow \forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y)$ is valid in first-order logic.

Comment: @Pilcrow I think that makes sense... Thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: @Pilcrow I've included an edit to my question specifying what I mean by FOL. I learned it from the book "Language, Proof, and Logic". The Axiom of Extensionality is a quantified sentence with a material conditional that runs in opposite direction than what you posted above. Ie, given any set x and set y, $\forall z (z \in x \iff z \in y) \implies x=y$, not $x=y \implies \forall z (z \in x \iff z \in y)$. Do you agree?

Comment: Using the expression $\forall a\ \forall b\ [\forall x\ (x \in a \iff x \in b) \implies a=b]$, proving that the antecedent is false does not prove that the consequent (a=b) is false.

Comment: @evianpring I agree, which is why I said that the axiom of extensionality is irrelevant when you wish to show that the two sets are distinct. What is used it the principle that identical objects satisfy the same formulas.

Comment: I guess it can be claimed that the axiom of extensionality is logically equivalent to the sentence that $\forall a \forall b [a\neq b \implies \exists x (x\in a\land x\notin b)]$ by contraposition, and hence one may argue that you used the axiom of extensionality in order to justify the inequality of the two sets $\{7,8,9\}$ and $\{7,8,10\}$. But contraposition only makes sense by propositional logic.

Comment: Where does step 5. come from?

Comment: @evianpring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that $\{7,8,9\}=\{7,8,10\}$ is a false stetement.

Let's assume the premise is true.

We have $\forall x(x\in \{7,8,9\} \iff x\in \{7,8,10\})$, by definition.

This implies that $9\in \{7,8,9\} \iff 9\in \{7,8,10\}$. This is where we use the universal instantation which you mentioned in your post. Since the statement is true for ANY value of x, that means that substituting x with ANYTHING will still gice us a true statement. In this example, we have substitued x with 9.

$9=7 \lor 9=8 \lor 9=9 \iff 9=7 \lor 9=8 \lor 9=10$, using your own definition of an element being part of a set.

$false \lor false \lor true \iff false \lor false \lor false$

$true \iff false$

$false$

The premise leads to an impossible conclusion. From this we can conclude that the sets are indeed not equal.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's investigate Axiom of Extensionality.

**Axiom of Extensionality**. For any two sets $A,B$,

\begin{equation}
(\text{for any }x\text{ we have }x\in A\text{ if and only if }x\in B)\Leftrightarrow A=B.
\end{equation}

In fact, Axiom of Extensionality is $\Rightarrow$ while $\Leftarrow$ follows the meaning of $=$. "$\Rightarrow$" is equivalent of say "If the extensions of $A$ and $B$ are the same then $A$ and $B$ are equal". "$\Leftarrow$" is equivalent to say "If $A$ and $B$ are equal then the extensions of $A$ and $B$ are the same" which is a truth in all the truth theory which is determined since if $A$ and $B$ are equal then everything of $A$ and $B$ are the same. *Although of this, we usually combine the two arrows together since "$\Leftarrow$" is obvious.*

Now turn to your problem. To show $\{7,8,9\}\neq\{8,9,10\}$ is easy that we just need to use "$\Leftarrow$" which is a truth while in fact not Axiom of Extentionality.

*Proof 1*. Suppose $\{7,8,9\}=\{8,9,10\}$. Since $7\in\{7,8,9\}$, then by $\{7,8,9\}=\{8,9,10\}$ we have $7\in\{8,9,10\}$, clearly contradicted to $7\notin\{8,9,10\}$.

*Proof 2*. Suppose $\{7,8,9\}=\{8,9,10\}$. Since $10\in\{8,9,10\}$, then by $\{7,8,9\}=\{8,9,10\}$ we have $10\in\{7,8,9\}$, clearly contradicted to $10\notin\{7,8,9\}$.